# Cannot Read Property 'Elements' of Undefined - in JS Console

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

HTML form (outputed thru PHP)

```
$retVal .= "<form id= 'importSampleDataForm' name = 'importSampleDataForm' onsubmit = \"return false\" >\n";

    // Form content edited out; it contains several dozen checkboxes

$retVal .= sprintf("<input type='button' class='wn_button' onclick='SaveMotorSkills();' value='Import Selected'>\n");
$retVal .= "</form>\n";
```

JavaScript   / Ajax

```
function SaveMotorSkills() // {{{
{
    // {{{ Ajax Header
    var httpRequest = CreateHttpRequest();
    if (!httpRequest) { 
        DialogFail('AJAX initialization error. ', 1 );
        return false; 
    } // }}}

    var params = '_SaveMotorSkills=1';
    for(i=0; i<document.importSampleDataForm.elements.length; i++) // line with error
    {
        params += "&" + document.importSampleDataForm.elements[i].name + 
            "=" + document.importSampleDataForm.elements[i].value ;
    }

    // edit out AJAX setup

    httpRequest.send(params);
    DialogSave("Saving...");
} // }}}
```

See "Line With Error Above" in `for` loop.  JS Console says

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined`

I have looked at this code so much my eyes can't take it anymore.  Does anyone else see anything I don't?  I can add more code if needed.

Comment: Are you running the function `SaveMotorSkills` from the footer, or after the page/html is on the screen? You should be.

Comment: It is run from a separate `.js` document and the form is already displayed on the screen.  When you click the button on bottom of form, this is when it is ran.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
document.getElementById('importSampleDataForm').elements.length
```

Also, [nested forms are not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms), so that also needs to be resolved.

Comment: that gives me new error:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of null `

Comment: @KickingLettuce, When does `SaveMotorSkills` run?  The new error is still on the same line, right?

Comment: I added this answer above in comments.

Comment: Are you in Chrome?  Try this: 1) load up web page. 2) press F12 3) click Console 4) run document.getElementById('importSampleDataForm').elements.length; and see what that gives you there.

Comment: It says same thing as my first comment;  'null'

Comment: Try just `document.getElementById('importSampleDataForm');`  maybe the html code isn't appearing on the page.

Comment: That says `null` as well.  When I inspect element; the correct form is there with the correct id/name.  The script isn't being ran until AFTER page has been loaded and then only if button is clicked.

Comment: I just noticed, this form is inside a form; would that cause the issue?  I removed the inner form and used the name of the outer form, now it seems to find it.

Comment: You got it.  Nested forms are not allowed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: You can add that as your answer and I will select.