# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined when submitting form

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML div output using PHP which when "Submit" is clicked, it should submit the form and fire a JS function. When submitted, the JS console in Chrome gives me the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined

My HTML (wrapped in a PHP heredoc)

```
<div id="tab5" class="tab">
     <div id="reopen_case_form">
        This Case has been previously closed by Workbooks Support. You can re-open this ticket at any time by providing a reason why you'd like to do so and clicking "Re-open Case".
        <table class="update_case">
         <tr><td style="padding: 10px">Summary:<input id="name" name="name" type="text" size="80" maxlength="255" class="required"/></td></tr>
         <tr><td><textarea id="description" name="description" cols="255" rows="50"></textarea></td></tr>
         <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <input type="file" class="file" name="file1" id="file1" style="display: inline">
            <input type="file" class="file" name="file2" id="file2" style="display: inline">
            <input type="file" class="file" name="file3" id="file3" style="display: inline">
          </td></tr>
      </table>
      <p><button type="submit" onclick="on_reopen_case()" style="float:left; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" value="reopen_case" id="reopen_case" name="reopen_case" class="quietbutton">Re-open Case</button></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function on_reopen_case() {
      if (!$("#reopen_case_form").valid()){ return false; }
      $('#reopen_case').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('#reopen_case').text('Re-opening case. Please wait...');
      document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
      $("#function").val("reopen_case");
      fade();
      $("#reopen_case_form").submit();
    };
  </script>
```

The form appears to submit but doesn't change the the button text to "Re-opening case" and it doesn't set #function to the specified value either.

Annoyingly I've used similar else where and this works:

```
<div id="tab3" class="tab">
     <div id="update_case_form">
        Provide a summary and detailed description of your update below, including screenshots where applicable. Click "Update Case" to submit your update to the Workbooks Support team.
      <table class="update_case">
         <tr><td style="padding: 10px">Summary:<input id="name" name="name" type="text" size="80" maxlength="255" class="required"/></td></tr>
         <tr><td><textarea id="description" name="description" cols="255" rows="50"></textarea></td></tr>
         <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <input type="file" class="file" name="file1" id="file1" style="display: inline">
            <input type="file" class="file" name="file2" id="file2" style="display: inline">
            <input type="file" class="file" name="file3" id="file3" style="display: inline">
          </td></tr>
      </table>
      <p><button type="submit" onclick="on_create_activity()" style="float:left; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" value="create_activity" id="create_activity" name="create_activity" class="quietbutton">Update Case</button></p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function on_create_activity() {
      if (!$("#update_case_form").valid()){ return false; }
      $('#create_activity').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('#create_activity').text('Updating case. Please wait...');
      document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
      $("#function").val("create_activity");
      fade();
      $("#update_case_form").submit();
    };
  </script>
```

I can't figure this out for the life of me where I'm going wrong! Help....

Comment: Where is to your `form`?

Comment: As @mariocatch is saying, you need to use the `<form>` element to use the `submit()` event. Change your `<div id="reopen_case_form">` to `<form..` and see what error you get then :)

Comment: Just tried that quickly and I now get a similar message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined

Comment: Do you create the `<div id="reopen_case_form">....` in a loop in php? Is it possible you have `n` number of `<div id="reopen_case_form">` in the same html document?

Comment: I'm creating tabs at the bottom of a screen, one of the tabs content is generated via a PHP foreach loop. It doesn't have a submit button though. The reference to reopen_case_form only exists the once...

Comment: looking at a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/32688197/689579. This error could be caused by un-unique `id`s. Have you verified that `#reopen_case_form` and `#reopen_case` are only defined once in the entire html document?

Comment: Thanks @Sean. I've just double checked the id's and that's the only place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* I may have figured this out... I was using nested forms which is apparently not allowed... [Cannot Read Property 'Elements' of Undefined - in JS Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600288/cannot-read-property-elements-of-undefined-in-js-console)

Thanks for the suggestions guys :)